# A crawler with smart support for sitemaps?

Tags: sitemap, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl a few hundred sites regularly. I would like to do this in the most efficient and consistent way possible. To do so it seems like the correct approach would be to use sitemaps where ever they are found. So first of all I am looking for a crawler that recognizes sitemaps and knows how to use them. The second issue, is how smart the crawler is. While some sites maintain their sitemaps perfectly, many do not. Their sitemaps may be out of date or in a non-standard format. Each situation needs a different approach.

So the question is whether this has been tackled in the open source (or commercial world)? Are there projects that do this well or well enough? I looked at a few of the open source crawlers that I identified and couldn't find this level of site crawling intelligence. If the answer is no. Are there any other good resources on this problem?

Comment: In the near future, we're planning to implement some of these features in [Site Visualizer](http://site-visualizer.com): crawling website by its XML sitemap, as well as crawling multiple sites in batch (using command line).

Answer (score 0):

Our open source crawler [Norconex HTTP Collector](http://www.norconex.com/product/collector-http/) does support sitemaps.  I do not know about the non-standard formats you've encountered, but it detects sitemaps at different locations (website root, listed in robots.txt, user-provided).   It supports sitemap sub-indices as well as compressed sitemaps.  Have a try and [give your feedback](https://github.com/Norconex/collector-http/issues) if you'd like to suggest new features.  If you know your way around Java, you can also swap the default sitemap-resolving implementation with your own.